# Migration from Pelican to Hugo

Tags: awk, hugo, pelican

I was reading an [article](https://www.sharats.me/posts/migrate-from-pelican-to-hugo/) showing how to migrate markdown files from Pelican to Hugo. I'm trying to understand what the awk script is doing. :

```
# begin block, executed once, 
# to set field separator, output fied separator & print 3 dashes
BEGIN { FS = ":"; OFS = ":"; print "---" }

# ??? 
!c && /^$/ { print "---\n"; c = 1 }

# user defined function?
c { print; next }

# user defined function?
!c {
    # lower first field
    $1 = tolower($1)

    # if first field is "date"
    if ($1 == "date") {
        # transform second field
        $2 = gensub(/ ([^.]+)\.([^.]+).([^.]+)/, " \\3-\\2-\\1", 1, $2)
        $2 = gensub(/-([0-9])-/, "-0\\1-", 1, $2)
    }

    if ($1 == "tags")
        $2 = " [" gensub(/[-a-z]+/, "'\\0'", "g", substr($2, 2)) "]"

    print
}
```

I don't really understand, what are `c` and `!c` are they user defined functions? Without the function keyword and without parameters? What is exactly the meaning of `c=1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` is a variable.  `c=1` sets the value of `c` to `1`

- `c` is a test of variable `c` and its true, other than `0`
- `!c` is a test of variable `c` and its true if `c` is not set or `0`
- `c { print; next }`  If `c` is set to some other than nothing or `0`, then `print` (will print the whole line since nothing other is specified).  `next` stop what you are doing and skip to next line and start over.